# Filtering a nested array - javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, filter

I have a nested array and each array has a string and an integer, the strings in some of the array are the same but i want to filter the array so that it only contains nested arrays with unique names and that have the highest values.  Here's an example of what i have and what i want:

```
[['a', 1],['a', 2],['a', 3],['b',2],['b',5]]
```

what i want to do is filter so that it contains this:

```
[['a', 3],['b', 5]]
```

I originally tried doing this with a for loop and an if statement, then a for loop and a while statement, when i looked at filtering but i'm not sure how to implement it where it will keep the string with the highest value, please help!!!!

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for grouping by the first element and get the maximum values by checking stored values.

```js
var array = [['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['a', 3], ['b', 2], ['b', 5]],
    result = Array.from(
        array.reduce((m, [k, v]) => m.set(k, m.has(k) ? Math.max(v, m.get(k)) : v), new Map)
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you like to keep the original arrays, you could store the array instead of the value and take later only the values of the map.

```js
var array = [['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['a', 3, 'bar'], ['b', 2], ['b', 5, 'foo']],
    result = Array.from(array
        .reduce(
            (m, a) => m.has(a[0]) && m.get(a[0])[1] > a[1] ? m : m.set(a[0], a),
            new Map
        )
        .values()
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
const data = [['a', 1],['a', 2],['a', 3],['b',2],['b',5]];

//in reducer we work with object instead of array
//efficient since we avoid doing an extra loop
const result = data.reduce((acc, cur)=>{

  //create variables from current array (ex: ['a', 1])
  const letter = cur[0];
  const value = cur[1];

  //Acc (accumulator) holds the highest values (ex {a: 1, b: 2} )
  //If the letter doesn't yet exist or if the cur value is higher we update the acc
  if(!acc[letter] || acc[letter] < value){
    acc[letter] = value;
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

//Not in the correct format, so we transform the result into the requested format
const final = Object.keys(result).map(key=>[key, result[key]]);

console.log(final);
```

Comment: it works!! thanks!! would you mind explaining it to me in depth?

Comment: I'd recommend marking Nina's solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/52755737/3589092 as the right answer.  It's much better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [['a', 1],['a', 2],['a', 3],['b',2],['b',5]]
const buf = {}
data.map(arr => {
    if(!buf[arr[0]] || buf[arr[0]] < arr[1])
        buf[arr[0]] = arr[1]
})
const result = Object.keys(buf).map(k => [k, buf[k]]);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: please explain your answer

Comment: @Rafael iterate data using map and store key and max value to buf object. after that, construct proper result array from buf object. since other answers are using reduce, my intent was to show different solution.

Comment: posting code without explanation is usually not helpful

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind. I thought "Here is solution" or "You can do this way" kind of explanation is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = [['a', 1],['a', 2],['a', 3],['b',2],['b',5]].reduce((res, arr) => {
    res[arr[0]] = !res[arr[0]] ? arr[1] : Math.max(res[arr[0]], arr[1])
    return res
}, {})
const result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => [key, obj[key]])
```

Comment: As you most likely know, posting only code without an explanation of how your code works is not good practice. Giving a brief summary of the code would help learners (like the question's author) a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [['a', 1],['a', 2],['a', 3],['b',2],['b',5]];
var result = data.sort(function(a,b){
    return Math.max(b[1]-a[1]);
});
var new_data= result.slice(0,2);
console.log(new_data.reverse());
```